# И слово "капище"

Tags: этимология

Продолжая "языческую" тему, хочу еще спросить о слове "капище". Одни говорят о том, что название восходит к языческим божкам "капам", другие, что это от слова "накапливать". Кто прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По Фасмеру, слово **капище** происходит из цслав., ст.-слав. *капиште* -- то же, от ст.-слав. **капь** ж. εϊδωλον "видение, призрак, образ", είχών "статуя, изображение". Связи с *накапливать (копить)* нет.

Comment: Как капище может происходить от церковно славянского, если, когда были капища церквей и в помине не было?

Comment: @Ася капища может и были, но слово, вероятно, было (чуть) другое. Речь о происхождении этого (современного) слова.

Answer (score -1):

В санскрите "kapiśa"(капища) - дух, солнце, ладан, фимиам.
Хотя, конечно, ничего, кроме кучи минусов я не получу - санскрит тут ненавидят, все русские слова должны происходить от тюрок, финнов и немцев.

Comment: В санскрите "kapiśa" — название рыжевато-коричневого цвета (происходит от kapi — обезьяна). Значение "солнце" тоже от цвета, видимо. Ещё есть значение "безоин (смола)" — и это тоже от цвета, а от него уже всякие ассоциации с запахом. А вот про значение "дух" что-то ни в одном санскритском словаре не сказано. Смею предположить, что это Вы в английском (который знаете ещё хуже санскрита) словаре так смотрели и перевели "spirit" как "дух", а не как "спирт".

Comment: kapiśa - N. of Śiva. -अयनः 1 the sun. -2 a deity.

Comment: Я не понял, какое слово мы обсуждаем. Я говорю о таком: कपिश, а Вы об этом अयननः? Вы хотя бы понимаете, что такое "N." в Вашей цитате? Это сокращение слова "Name" (Имя). Вы можете дать ссылку или хотя бы сделать скриншот или фото всей словарной статьи?

Comment: И заодно, подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком основании Вы решили, что deity переводится как "дух"? В доступных мне словарях такого значения нет. Я надеюсь, что когда Вы приведёте скриншот словарной статьи, мы разберёмся, откуда взялся "дух". Впрочем, возможно, что Вы смотрите какой-то мусорный словарь.